# Putting music theme A onto theme B background

Tags: terminology

A friend has shown me 2 piano books she has where a classical piece is used as the background theme and another non-classical piece is overlaid at intervals.  For example, a piece begins with Liebestraum, and after a few bars it becomes Great Is Thy Faithfulness with a slight adjustment but keeping the Liebestraum harmonic and rhythmic style.  GITF drops out and returns, but Liebestraum finishes the piece.  The only term I can find is "Mashup", which isn't quite right for this.  Is there a name for when one piece is "dropped into" another piece in this manner?

Comment: And the right answer is... "Music". Seriously tho, it's literally "Chord substitution" but that name's already taken, so what is it?

Answer (score 3):

A technique I liked to practice in my compositions without ever asking for an expression for it.

Now I’ve found the term **“blend”**:

In the following video a comment says: *the tunes have been **blended** into the music.*

Searching for *blend two songs* I came to the term you mention: mash-up

and this here:

https://www.wikihow.com/Blend-Two-Songs-Together

Well,  I think *merging, mixing, mash-up* are all terms derived from the music technic scene:

> A mash-up is similar to a DJ mix in that the DJ provides few, if any, significant new sounds to the music, other than those required to blend already-existing music. A mash-up differs from a DJ mix in that two or more songs are playing simultaneously, rather than one after the other. In general, in a mash-up, each original source will contribute more-or-less equally to the final work. There is no requirement, however, that the entire mix of each source be used; a common mash-up technique is to use the vocals from one song mixed with the music of another. Songs involved in a mash-up can be indicated with Mash-up Relationship Type.

https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Terminology

But the idea to mix two or more themes together in a composition is much older: already in Baroque era there was a practice to sing several songs together like canons or a *quodlibet.*

In my view this technic could be simply called a **counterpoint** (using another existing song as c.p.

One of my favorite examples: *Let the sunshine in* and  *Manchester England* from the musical HAIR.

P.S.

Another idea: How about *assembling*? (related with *Ensemble* for a group of musicians playing together ...

**Edit**:

When listening today the Asian sketches by Borodin I reminded your question:

He did exactly what you’re asking and “merged” two tunes together . He calls it(double) **counterpoint**.

> *The composer told a very surprised and impressed friend about the excellent processing of the themes: “Before I composed this piece, I had already thought up the two themes - the Russian and the Oriental, which were then both brought together in **double counterpoint;** and only later did I develop the entire accessory for this orchestra picture."*

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Steppes_of_Central_Asia